# Returning newly created element from jquery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

is it possible to make that widget that is initialized on some DOM element returns some other element.

```
var ulwidget= $("<ul>")
                .widgetList(
                    {
                        attribute1: x
                        tabIndex: tabIndex++
                    });
```

ulwidget is ul element but I'm wondering if it could be any other element created in widget

Comment: you just need to modify the return value of the widgetList function. It can return anything you want it to.

Comment: it is jquery widget that returns element on which is instantiated. In this case UL. Code is inside jQuery widget factory but I assume there is a way to return some other element. Changing element by this.element = (some new element) seems wrong and doesn't work in my case.